# Run java Selenium in command prompt

Tags: java, selenium

I have this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http:\\www.yahoo.com");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to run it in `cmd`. For this reason I call the following commands in a `.bat` file.

```
javac -classpath "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-firefox-driver-2.42.2.jar" Test.java
java Test
```

The following error is returned:

```
C:\selenium-2.42.2>javac -classpath "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-server-standalo
ne-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\sel
enium-firefox-driver-2.42.2.jar" Test.java

C:\selenium-2.42.2>java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/f
irefox/FirefoxDriver
        at Test.main(Test.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Firefox
Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Also, the following information will help:

1. `java -version` got:

   java version "1.8.0_05"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
2. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox>firefox.exe -v | more
   Mozilla Firefox 30.0`

Maybe this post will marked as duplicate but I followed others suggestions without any success. Can you please cast some light the situation?

[Here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/452203/selenium-jars.zip) is the `jar` files I use.

Thanks!

**PS:** Win7 64bit

Comment: Try using `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`.

Comment: With the same `jar` files, cmd returns similar error: `the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/W
ebDriver`. Strange again. Is anything wrond in `jar` file loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first command `javac` builds the classes, but does not embed the dependencies into the final jar file, which is what the error is telling you: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. You still need to provide the same dependencies when you run the class.

```
javac -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar" Test.java
java -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar" Test
```

The selenium-java.jar should be enough for your case. Have a look at the graphic here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp to see how the different selenium jars are contained in each other.

I do not believe you can use just `javac` alone to embed the dependencies into the final .jar. You will need other tools.

Comment: Is there any difference between `-classpath` and `-cp`. In any case I run your suggestion instead of mine (second snippet) but cmd returns the same error after running `java Test`.

Comment: Sorry, got distracted in my first response. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am running your snippet but I am get this error: `C:\selenium-2.42.2>java -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar" Test Error: Could not find or load main class Test`. Any ideas on that? By the way a `Test.class` file is created in the folder.`Sorry for my ignorance:)

Comment: You really should consider using a _proper_ IDE, such as Eclipse or one of the others, that does all this work for you!

Comment: __At last, the corerct command is__: `javac -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.j‌​ar" Test.java` and `java -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;.;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2‌​.jar" Test`.

Comment: @Thoth: Hi, i have the same problem today. And i'v tried with your solution. The first work very well: javac -cp "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.j‌​ar". BUT the second doesn't work (C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;.;selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2‌​.jar" Test). I'v got Error: "Error: ExecutionEngine main class could not be found or loaded". Can you help?